# C++ gettid() was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++11, linux-kernel, system-calls, boost-thread

A simple program is: 
I would like to get the thread ID of both of the threads using this gettid function. I do not want to do the sysCall directly. I want to use this function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/date.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

boost::thread thread_obj;
boost::thread thread_obj1;

void func(void)
{
    char x;
    cout << "enter y to interrupt" << endl;
    cin >> x;
     pid_t tid = gettid();
    cout << "tid:" << tid << endl;
    if (x == 'y') {
        cout << "x = 'y'" << endl;    
        cout << "thread interrupt" << endl;
    }
}

void real_main() {

   cout << "real main thread" << endl;
    pid_t tid = gettid();
    cout << "tid:" << tid << endl;

    boost::system_time const timeout = boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(3);
    try {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(timeout);
    }
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted &) {
        cout << "thread interrupted" << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    thread_obj1 = boost::thread(&func);
    thread_obj = boost::thread(&real_main);
    thread_obj.join();
}
```

It gives Error on compilation; The use of gettid() has been done according to the man page:

```
$g++ -std=c++11 -o Intrpt Interrupt.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread
Interrupt.cpp: In function ‘void func()’:
Interrupt.cpp:17:25: error: ‘gettid’ was not declared in this scope
      pid_t tid = gettid();
```

Answer (score 44):

This is a silly glibc bug.  Work around it like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)
```

Comment: that's not a bug, man-page states that, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681498/142561

Comment: was fixed in glibc 2.30

Comment: Describing buggy behavior doesn't make it not a bug, it just makes it an acknowledged bug.  Glad it was fixed.

Answer (score 7):

The man page you refer to can be read online [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html). It clearly states:

> *Note*: There is no glibc wrapper for this system call; see NOTES.

and

> **NOTES**
>
> Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using syscall(2).
>
> The thread ID returned by this call is not the same thing as a POSIX thread ID (i.e., the opaque value returned by pthread_self(3)).

So you can't. The only way to use this function is through the syscall.

But you probably shouldn't anyway. You can use `pthread_self()` (and compare using `pthread_equal(t1, t2)`) instead. It's possible that `boost::thread` has its own equivalent too.

Comment: There's nothing "clearly stated" about saying "there's no glibc wrapper".

Comment: was fixed in glibc 2.30

Answer (score 6):

Additional to the solution provided by Glenn Maynard it might be appropriate to check the glibc version and only if it is lower than 2.30 define the suggested macro for gettid().

```
#if __GLIBC__ == 2 && __GLIBC_MINOR__ < 30
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)
#endif
```