# ubuntu cannot find "gettid" function?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, pthreads, posix

I've got a very small program to test thread related stuff:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid=getpid();
    pid_t tid=gettid();
    printf("%d,%d\n",pid,tid);
    return 0;
}
```

Within vim editor, I focus on 'gettid' and Shift-K, the man page of gettid says it's inside sys/types. No problem, when I compile it, there's error:

```
g++ mythread.cpp 
mythread.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mythread.cpp:7:22: error: ‘gettid’ was not declared in this scope
     pid_t tid=gettid();
                  ^
```

I'm on ubuntu1604 with new gcc version. How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ gettid() was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680550/c-gettid-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use  : pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
as this cant be called directly.